# How To Focus Cursor in Textarea With Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to focus cursor to specific line. I'm getting line's number whit this code

`taid=document.getElementById(element);`
`line = taid.value.substr(0, taid.selectionStart).split("\n").length;`

then I make some proccess. After that I want to focus to "line" number. How can I do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can start your research here, for example: http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/

Comment: Sorry I didn't write ; I'm trying to find a solution without selection range functions